# Deciding on two or three interaction effects for mixed effects logistic regression in r

Tags: r, logistic-regression, interaction

I am trying to determine if I need a two- or three-way interaction effect and if my random slopes addition makes sense in this model.

The overall question is how do these variables below affect the prevalence of a disease in shrimp.
With fixed and random effects here is model #1:

```
glmer(disease ~ year + sample.site + temperature + maturity + (1|trawl.set), 
data = x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
```

I know that temperature will vary between year and between sample site so I added in a three way interaction:
model#2:

```
glmer(disease ~ year * sample.site * temperature + maturity + (1|trawl.set), 
data = x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
```

I built on model #2 and also added a random slopes effect because we want to model the presence of the disease as a function of year, site, temperature and maturity, knowing that this relationship will vary among sample sites.
model #3:

```
glmer(disease ~ year * sample.site * temperature * maturity + (1+sample.site|trawl.set), 
    data = x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
```

I have compared many different models including:
a) null,
b) interaction effect between just temperature and year with no random slopes,
c) 3 way interaction (shown in model #3) without random slopes,
d) just fixed effects (i.e., no interaction) with Year as the random slopes,
e) just fixed effect (i.e., no interaction) with sample.site as the random slopes.

After comparing all of these models, model #3 is the most significant and has the lowest AIC value, but I still don't know if this is the right approach.

Does anyone have advice on how to proceed?